# Android : How To convert Object to String

Tags: java, android, object

I try to put all label or object my view into one arraylist as below :

```
public class UpdateQuisioner extends Fragment {
    EdiTtext essay_tt_no1, essay_tt_no2;
    RadioGroup option_grup_tt_no1, option_grup_tt_no2;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                static ArrayList<View> ListOfView = new ArrayList<View> ();
                View [] view = {essay_tt_no1, option_grup_tt_no1, essay_tt_no2, option_grup_tt_no2};
                ListOfView.addAll(Arrays.asList(view));
                for (int i = 0; i < ListOfView.size(); i++){
                    Log.i("View ", ListOfView.get(i).toString());

                }
            }
```

It doesn't give me name of label widget when I check in my logcat, but gives me String like this `android.widget.EditText@41f08618`. Is there anything wrong or something wrong with my code?

Comment: you creating a customized list view am right.

Comment: `ListOfView.get(i).getText().toString()` But it won't work in `onCreateView`. Put In button click.

Comment: The fact that `toString()` which is basically what you are calling does not provide any useful information does not mean that your `View` does not contain them. Use a more specific method to get the info you need.

Comment: Please be clear about what property of your views you are trying to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying answer now that I understand you want the resource identifier of your views:

```
Resources res = getResources();
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfView.size(); i++){
    int id = ListOfView.get(i).getId();
    try {
        Log.i("View ", res.getResourceName(id));
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("Unknown id " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've know the way to check it's `EditTex`t or `RadioGroup`, I don't know how to check the label of my view from `ArrayList`.

Comment: OK, then tell me what it is you mean by "label of my view"

Comment: You're trying to check the "variable of my view"? That doesn't make sense either. Are you trying to print the text in the EditText objects? Are you trying to print the resource identifier you use on those views in your XML?

Comment: yes, I'm  trying to print the resource identifier Iuse on those views in my XML

Comment: This is what I need, thank you so much Bruce, I'm Sorry If I make some Unclear question :)

Answer (score 0):

It won't provide specific field detail in `toString`. But it will print object's hascode along with class name. Check below method in `Object.class` file.

```
 public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Comment: yes... can you tell me to give a string of label without being hashcode String?

Comment: You have to override toString method which I would not suggest. Rather then go for `ListOfView.get(i).getText()`

Comment: not all my `ListofView` contain `EditText`, it also contain `RadioGroup` and `Spinner`

Answer (score 0):

Can you override toString method of View class instance?
And in this method return what you want to see in log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Log.i("View ", ListOfView.get(i).getText());
```

[look it at http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText())

Answer (score -1):

Its not found the label. You give the views to print so its shows those string.